# How do i compare a list and a list inside a list

Tags: python, grok

```
x = input("Please enter your DNA sequence: ")
k = []
hi = [["Phenylalanine","UUU"],["Leucine","UUA"]]
z = {'A' : 'U', 'T' : 'A', 'G' : 'C', 'C' : 'G'}
for i in x:
  l = z[i]
  k.append(l)
k = ''.join(k)
print("Your RNA sequence is :" + k)
t = [k[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(k), 3)]
for t in t:
  a = hi[2]
  b = t[1]
  o = [i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]
  print("The Amino acid cequence is" + (o) + ".")
```

I want a code that if I typed AAAAAT it would change it to [UUU, UUA] then find it in the hi list and print "The Amino Acid Sequence is Phenylalanine, Leucine."
I do not how
Can someone please help?

Comment: I would recommend starting by researching on what a [dictionary in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few prominent issues with the code segment:

1. `a = hi[2]` : `hi` has only 2 elements but you're trying to access the third one
2. `for t in t` do not iterate through a list with the list variable itself.
3. Name your variables such that we can understand the intention

Having said that, a straightforward approach to solve this problem will be to make `hi` a dictionary

```
hi_dict = {"UUU":"Phenylalanine","UUA":"Leucine"}
```

And keep the result string outside the loop.

```
answer= "The Amino acid cequence is "
for ti in t:
  answer = answer + hi_dict [ti] +" "
print(answer)
```

Example :

```
Please enter your DNA sequence: AAAAAT
Your RNA sequence is :UUUUUA
The Amino acid cequence is Phenylalanine Leucine
```

Comment: Ive changed my code to this
but it says key error "UUU"
x = input("Please enter your DNA sequence: ")
k = []
hi_dict = {"Phenylalanine":"UUU","Phenylalanine":"UUC"}
z = {'A' : 'U', 'T' : 'A', 'G' : 'C', 'C' : 'G'}
for i in x:
  l = z[i]
  k.append(l)
k = ''.join(k)
print("Your RNA sequence is :" + k)
t = [k[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(k), 3)]
print (t)
answer = ""
for lol in t:
  answer = answer + hi_dict[lol]
print(answer)

Comment: Please compare your `hi_dict` to mine, you'll see what you did wrong

Comment: thank u now i know whagt i did wrong
and my friend also told me

Answer (score 0):

```
DAN_TO_AA = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                  
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_', 
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W', 
    }

DAN_TO_RNA = {"A": "U", "T": "A", "G": "C", "C": "G"}

seq = "AAAAAT"
rna = " ".join(
    [DAN_TO_RNA.get(seq[i : i + 3], seq[i : i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)]
)
protein = "".join([DAN_TO_AA.get(seq[i : i + 3], "-") for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)])
print(f"Your RNA sequence is {rna}")
print(f"The Amino acid cequence is {protein}")
```